# cannot fetch data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch, jsonplaceholder

I am having trouble getting the data from jsonplaceholder.com

I tried using promise:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

[image: using promise]

Then I tried the same thing using async function:

```js
async function fetchUsers() {
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const data = await resp.json()
  console.log(data)
}

fetchUsers()
```

[image: using async function]

Either way, I get an error.

I am studying a course where the tutor had no problem fetching the function using both async and promise:

[image: screenshot from the course lecture]

Please help

Comment: What does the Network tab of your dev tools say?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with this. Can you even open https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users in your browser as a direct link?

Comment: You cant fetch from a new tab page. Navigate to google.com and try the same thing again.

Comment: @Phil yes i had so issue opening the link directly

Comment: @phil: code uploaded as requested

Comment: @leadbassist That code has already been added to the question in [revision 3](/revisions/69156744/3)…

Comment: @hacKaTun3s you are right! its a silly error from my end. Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly, when I run this in a new tab console (Chrome 93.0.4577.63), it shows that the script is running from `new-tab-page/:1` which would have made diagnosing this problem much easier

Answer (score 4):

[@HacKaTun3s's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156744/cannot-fetch-data-from-jsonplaceholder-typicode-com/69157609#comment122230233_69156744) worked for me: "You cant fetch from a new tab page. Navigate to google.com and try the same thing again."